# Building a library with Vue, Typescript and Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, vuejs2, semantic-ui

I little while ago i decided to turn a vue project i had into a library so i could reuse the components i had in other projects.

I followed some guidelines and almost everything works, the problem is when i use the lib in another project and use the components, some of the components from one of the dependencies give me this errors:

```
Unknown custom element: <sui-modal> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I get this for every element of the modal component.

Now, what could this be? something with webpack? or do i have to export this modules from semantic in some way? In the original project this used to work.

Comment: Do you have an example using the <sui-modal> component? It is hard to figure out the issue without a proper context.

Comment: I replaced the the semantic ui lib and now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the the semantic ui lib and now it works fine

Comment: replaced where? Or what was the replacement? You said:
`I followed some guidelines`
what guidelines, can you link them? 
I am trying to make typescript component lib for company projects and did not found for vue + ts + webpack yet, thanks.

Comment: Actually the problem i faced here was pretty specific, turns out the css lib i was using at that time was not compatible with webpack, so i replaced it with another lib, that was complatible with it.

Comment: It's been a while since i did this, and it's probably outdated, but if you want to take a look at my project configuration i can link you: https://github.com/Hggo/vue-generic-application